# How to split single large hex value row text file into columns using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I know it's very simple question to experienced person but I new in jupyter notebook please give me your valueable answer.I have hex value text file like 0A BC AD 4A 3E 4F FF FE 23 45 6D.....UPTO 3487 continues series value. I want a 4 paired hex value column's rows in jupyter notebook
Output like

```
0A BC AD 4A                                                                                                    
3E 4F FF FE
23 45 .. ..
```

so on

```
Import pandas as pd 
f = pd.read_csv('c\\file.txt') 
f
```

Comment: A sample of 'file.txt' would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ')
df
```

I think you're probably missing the `sep=' '`, which is important, as the default encoding for a CSV is a comma.